# find the period of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

I've found the period of this trigonometric function,
$$y=\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x)$$.

when n （$n\neq2$）is odd, the period is $2\pi$,

when n is even, the period is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

but how to proof it?

Comment: What about when $n=2$?

Comment: This can easily be generalized for $\sin^ax+\cos^bx$.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the periods of both terms, the period of the sum is the least common multiple of both.

You could express the sine and cosine using complex exponentials, often that makes trigonometric identities trivial.